# Large Computations in Loops, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, optimization

I am working on an optimization problem and currently using fmincon to minimize a relatively complex objective function . This problem can take up to one day to converge, therefore I decided to feed the solver (fmincon) with gradient vector and Hessian matrix. So far I have a threefold increase in speed, but I think there is a way to optimize the following code which calculates my gradient vector and is called over a million times:

```
gradf = zeros(1,length(ftprm));
if nargout > 1
    %% gradient with respect to q0s
    for j=1:nprd
        s = 0;
        for n = 1:nstgs
           s = s + 2 * (obsQ(n,j) - Q(n+1,j)) * exp(-n/tau(j));
        end
        gradf(1,j) = -s;
    end
    %% gradient with respect to taus
    for j = 1:nprd
        s = 0;
        dqjndtauj = 0;
        for n = 1:nstgs
            FijIin = sum(F((j-1)*ninj+1:j*ninj).*injpls(n,:));
            dqjndtauj = dqjndtauj * exp(-1/tau(j)) + ...
                 Q(n,j)*1/tau(j)^2 * exp(-1/tau(j)) - ...
                 1/(tau(j)^2)*exp(-1/tau(j))*FijIin;
            s = s + 2 * (obsQ(n,j) - Q(n+1,j)) * dqjndtauj;
        end
        gradf(1,nprd+j) = -s;
    end
    %% gradient with respect to Fis
    for j = 1:nprd
        for i = 1:ninj
            s1 = 0;
            for n = 1:nstgs
                s2 = 0;
                for k = 1:n
                    s2 = s2 + exp(-(n-k)/tau(j))*(1-exp(-1/tau(j)))*injpls(k,i);
                end
                s1 = s1 + 2*(obsQ(n,j)-Q(n+1,j))*s2;
            end
            gradf(1,2*nprd+(j-1)*ninj+i)=-s1;
        end
    end
end
```

My question is simply: what are the best ways to reduce the computation time for this code? BTW, fmincon is already using parallel computation, and I know that if I use parfor in this case, it will have negative effects. Also, I can have access to any toolbox or features that is necessary, since the project sponsor will pay for it!

Comment: Do not understand the code entirely but why cant you do all the three gradient computations in one for loop? Seems to me that each is independent of the other.

Comment: I just finished the code and I kept them in separate loops to make less mistakes. I will do your suggestion, but I am still looking for more faults that may exist in my code. BTW, i can explain whichever part of the code that is not clear to you.

Comment: I would ask you to provide some comments on the variables. Otherwise, it makes it hard to follow for e.g. Q, obsQ,nprd,...

Comment: I study petroleum engineering and we are trying to model a common enhanced oil recovery technique. Here, nprd and ninj and nstgs are the number of producers, the number of injectors, and the number of injection/production stages respectively. obsQ and Q are observed and modeled flow rates at producers. q0s, taus, and Fis are model parameters. I hope this information helps.

Comment: Hi! Well, since your code looks almost like a C code (i.e., mostly just simple arithmetic operations), I guess that rewriting it as a mex should be fairly simple (see e.g., http://www.shawnlankton.com/2008/03/getting-started-with-mex-a-short-tutorial/).

That generally brings huge performance boost in a loop-heavy code.

Comment: I'd suggest that you use the spacebar more. One of your lines is 102 characters long without a single space. When sharing code, readability is paramount. Itsnoteasytoreadthingsthatarewirrtenlikethis. See what I mean?

Comment: ItMightBeEasyToReadSoemthingLikeThis and this is the followed convention in many places while naming variables. Also please comment your code.